# Getting this error " Unknown column 'bus_name' in 'field list' "

Tags: php, mysql

This code works perfect in localhost, but when I load it on a remote web server I am getting the alert: Error & after clicking the OK button, I get this error : Unknown column 'bus_name' in 'field list'.
Any help? Thanks in advance.

Action page:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
error_reporting("-1");

$bus_name=$_POST['bus_name'];
$bus_no=$_POST['bus_no'];
$ticket_number=$_POST['number'];
$booker_name=$_POST['name'];

$sql="INSERT INTO ticket_details(`bus_name`,`bus_no`,`ticket_number`, `booker_name`)
VALUES('$bus_name','$bus_no','$ticket_number','$booker_name')";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($result)
{
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
    "alert('Thank You');".
    "location.href='index.php';".
    "</script>";
}
else {
 echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
    "alert('Error');".
    "location.href='javascript:index.php';".
    "</script>";


}
die(mysql_error());

mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: give space between "ticket_details (`bus_name`..."

Comment: It likely means exactly what it says: you don't have such a field in your table.

Comment: i think i ve my problem in uploaded database

Comment: Your site would be **very** easy to exploit using SQL injection. At *least* escape your variables. [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @h2ooooooo Is there copy-pasta friendly markdown for the MySQL deprecated text?

Comment: @TimothyChoi I have a simple coded [bookmark](http://pastebin.com/szgBEYRu) that opens up the comment box, pastes this response and all I have to do is click "add comment".

Answer (score 0):

Your html code is not provided here. just check in html if the field 'bus_name' is provided in the same case and not in uppercase or lowercase with any alphabet in it.

If this is the case, it will work fine in windows server but not in a linux server.

Comment: i think i ve my problem in uploaded database

Comment: check for the case sensitivity issue in the table fields also.

Answer (score 0):

check your database column `bus_name` make sure there is no space before and after the column name(please edit that database field and try to check if spaces are there or not), make sure the column name is not in upper case in db table.

Comment: i think i ve my problem in uploaded database

Comment: make sure there is no space in the column name `bus_name` in insert query and check the case sensitivity

Comment: use this line before your insert query  `echo "INSERT INTO ticket_details(`bus_name`,`bus_no`,`ticket_number`, `booker_name`)
VALUES('$bus_name','$bus_no','$ticket_number','$booker_name')";`  paste the echo result in phpmyadmin and check how the result is coming

Comment: can u plz post the whole echo result

Answer (score 0):

In your server database you have a different name for the column `bus_name`.Use the same name for column `bus_name` in server database,which you used in localhost database.